# Match regular strings

Tags: regex

I want to match strings like `ababbabbba` in which the number of `b`s increases one by one and ends to `a`.

So it should match:

```
aba
ababba
ababbabbba
...
```

I tried `^(a(\2?b))+a$` which you can [see here](http://regex101.com/r/vV3cG8). but it matches `ababa` too. I can't go anymore, really confused with backreferences!

***Edit***

Well, many thanks goes to @Alan Moore, I made his regex a little shorter and finally I introduced it to you too:

`^(ab((?(2)\2b)))+a$`

Comment: Are you sure you want to make it with regex? In general they have weakness (because regex has no "memory" in normal sense). Also, please, specify your language, cause some possibilities are available in special context only

Comment: @AlmaDo Yes since it's a regular string I want to achieve that with just Regular Expressions, I don't want a piece of code. It's better all expressions goes to be Perl Compatible.

Comment: More confusion between formal regular expressions and the actual tools we have in modern languages, which are more powerful than the formal construct.  A "language" containing strings with monotonically-lengthening runs of `b`s is not "regular" in the formal sense, and thus cannot be matched with a formal regular expression - but formal regular expressions don't have backreferences.  Just remember that when someone says your string class is not "regular", it's a statement about formal definitions, not an insult, and the fact that you can make something work does not disprove the statement.

Comment: @MarkReed I refer you to Alan Moore's answer, specially the last paragraph.

Comment: I don't share Alan's dismissive attitude toward the formal side, revo, but beyond that we are saying the same thing: formal regexes can't do this, but our tools are more powerful and therefore can. More specifically, I was addressing your comments on other answers about not being able to see the irregularity. We're using a very specific definition of "regular" which has little to do with the normal English sense of the word here.  It is the "increasing number of b's" criterion which makes your language irregular in the formal sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex works for me:

`^(?:a((?(1)\1b|b)))+a$`

As with most regex flavors, PHP doesn't like to refer to a captured group from within that same group.  But if it's inside a conditional, the regex engine can see that it won't have to process the backreference before the group has had a chance to participate in the match.  If it chooses to look, that is; some regex flavors reject forward references (as they're called) as invalid syntax no matter what you do.

On a side note, don't bother trying to understand regular grammars, regular languages, that kind of thing.  Those refer to what we call around here *theory-pure regular expressions*, which are very different from the *regexes* we use in the real world.  So when someone tells you that you can't match a certain string because it's not *regular*, don't listen.  You're probably talking to a computer science major who doesn't realize how irregular regexes really are. ;)

Comment: You! are.. Awesome! you did that damn trick on my regex. I made it better to look shorter  `^(ab((?(2)\2b)))+a$`. Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

[This regex](http://regex101.com/r/lU3cL8) should work:

```
^(?=a)((b*)a(?=\2ba))+\2ba$
```

Breakdown:

- `^(?=a)` makes sure the string starts with `a` (crucial for the next bit)
- `((b*)a(?=\2ba))+` matches the following as much as it can:

  - `(b*)a` captures any number of `b`'s (including none of them), and makes sure there's an `a` next to it. The lookahead at the beginning is needed to make sure the number of `b`'s starts at 0.
  - `(?=\2ba)` checks that this is followed by the same number of `b`'s plus one, and another `a` at the end. This enforces the "number of `b`'s increases by 1" rule.
- `\2ba$` then makes sure the last lookahead is at the end of the string.

Comment: Tnx, Before completion I should say it doesn't match on `aba`

Comment: and also matches `abbabbba` which it shouldn't.

Comment: @revo (hopefully) fixed everything

Comment: +1 Perfect! but will wait for other answers yet till accept yours

Comment: It doesn't match "a" though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions parse [regular grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar). They can't parse grammars which are not regular. You can study rules of regular grammars in link above or somewhere else and try to build regular grammar for your example but I'm doubt that you will succeed. How will you express that next chain of `b`s is longer than previous one?

If I were you I would use parser-combinators technique for this example.

Comment: `number of bs increases one by one `

Comment: I don't see any irregularity with it then, that's why regular expressions are made for their advanced way

Comment: I doubt that you we express that next chain of bs should be longer that previous one.

Comment: We can't check and compare, but we can ensure that the next one always has a more `b` of the late one.

Comment: No, we can't. If we can I want to see the grammar description

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43982/discussion-between-kakadu-and-revo)

Comment: My regex won't match `ababbba` but it will match `ababba` so it confirms the increase of `b` to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a shorter regex:

```
^(^ab|\1b)*a$
```

Which matches `a` too. If you don't want `a` alone, then use `+` instead of `*` for the quantifier.